# Objective C simple contact form?

Tags: objective-c, contact-form

I want to have a way that people can send me suggestions through the app via email (Without Database and php). I thought that i could have just a couple text field for the name,email adresse, subject and the message itself then code it in order to send those datas to my email but i can't find a way to do it... Is there an easy way to create a contact form? Is it possible even ?

Comment: did you search github / cocoacontrols ?

Comment: No... I'm new when it comes to coding.. I barely know how to write a complete app. I tried looking at stuff on github before but it seems really complicated.

Comment: Yep, building an app and learning new stuff can be complicated sometimes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple to begin with. If you want to send an e-mail, just use `MFMailComposeViewController` and add a subject and a little body txt (and the recipient obviously).

Later, you can add other interfaces, but, any kind of contact form would usually be implemented by calling to your server rather than sending an e-mail (i.e. to a php page on your server).